# How to add an address I found in Google Maps into Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-maps

Is there a way in desktop browsers to import an address I found in Google Maps into Google Calendar?

Comment: Can  you not simply copy-paste?

Comment: well not really. I have been searching for a Doctor and google maps knows its name and phone number. So, I have to copy all three fields and paste it into the new contact. I was hoping that google knows about all this and proposes a new contact...